# Is it permitted to pray in state of Janabah, if time will run out in doing ghusl?

Tags: salat, fiqh, taharah

I want to ask, If a person wakes up at home from his regular night sleep in a state of Janabah and his condition (after he wakes up)  is that:

1) he is not deprived of water at his home.

2) he has not yet taken a bath (in a state of Janabah)

3) He is also has not done the Fajr prayer (Subuh).

4) He wakes up at 5 minutes (or less) before sunrise.

What should he do in this case,  should he take a bath first and risk missing / skipping the Subuh prayer by bypassing  its time limit (sunrise)? (because taking a bath in a state of Janabah will surely take longer than normal bath,  presumably more that 10 minutes)

Or should he just take a regular wudu right after he wakes up and attempt to do the Subuh prayer without taking a bath (praying in a state of Janabah)?  Thus making it possible for him to start the Subuh prayer within its time limit.

Which one?

Regards

Comment: He can't pray a valid prayer unless performing ghusl. So there actually is no second option.

Comment: Sorry changed my mind. What if the case is you only had 5 minutes?

Comment: Even then you should not pray without ghusl, just leave the prayer and ask for forgiveness. Praying with impurity is a separate sin on its own and it would be worst than not praying at all.

Answer (score 2):

The matter is simple as said by @Yas in the comment and in the given answer.

A major condition for the validity of a prayer is ritual purity, without it your prayer is invalid and there's no second option to obtain it except with performing ghusl. It doesn't make a difference whether there's even 1 min. left or less that's the view of the majority of scholars other said he is allowed to perform tayammum:

> Ibn Qudaamah said, explaining the view of the majority: If water is available but the effort to acquire it and use it means that the time will end, it is not permissible for him to do tayammum, whether he is at home or travelling, according to the majority of scholars including al-Shaafa’i, Abu Thawr, Ibn al-Mundhir, and as-haab al-ra’i. It was narrated from al-Awzaa’i and al-Thawri that he may do tayammum. That was narrated from them by al-Waleed ibn Muslim. End quote from al-Mughni (1/166). (Source islamqa #[94311](https://islamqa.info/en/94311))

Ibn Qudamah added in his al-Mughni -see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=300&idto=300&bk_no=15&ID=274) in Arabic-:
 <sub>In the following I will translate from Arabic, if I didn't add a source of the translation, the translation is mine take it carefully!</sub>

> قال الوليد  : فذكرت ذلك  لمالك ،  وابن أبي ذئب ،  وسعيد بن عبد العزيز ، فقالوا : يغتسل ، وإن طلعت الشمس ; وذلك لقول الله تعالى : { فلم تجدوا ماء فتيمموا  } وحديث  أبي ذر ، وهذا واجد للماء ; ولأنه قادر على الماء ، فلم يجز له التيمم ، كما لو لم يخف فوت الوقت ; ولأن الطهارة شرط ، فلم يبح تركها خيفة فوت وقتها ، كسائر شرائطها .
>   Al-Walid said: I've mentioned that (about Tayammum) to Malik and ibn Abi a-Dh'ib and Sa'id ibn 'Abd al-'Aziz they answered: he must take a ghusl, even if the sun rises, because of what Allah the Almighty said: "...and find no water, ...([4:43](https://legacy.quran.com/4/43) and [5:6](https://legacy.quran.com/5/6)) and the hadith of abu Dharr, and this person actually has water, and is able to use it, so tayammum is not allowed for him. Similar to the case he didn't worry missing the prayer on time: the taharah (ritual purity) is a condition (for the validity), so it is not allowed to leave it aside worrying to miss the prayer on time, euqaly to any other condition of the prayer.

The hadith of abu Dharr referred to here seems to be [this hadith](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=85&bookhad=1335) which appears in at-Tabaranis al-Awsat which is quoted with somewhat different wordings or additions in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/332), [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1103240) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/124) and others with the important statement:

> ..."Clean earth is a means for ablution for a Muslim, even for ten(<sub>In at_Tabarni's al-Awsat</sub> twenty)  years (he does not find water); but when you find water, you should make it touch your skin, for that is better"

You may further read in the fatwa above:

> Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: If a person wakes up at the end of the time for prayer and he is junub and is afraid that if he does ghusl the time for the prayer will end, he should do ghusl and pray, even if the time does end. The same applies to one who forgets it. End quote from al-Ikhtiyaaraat al-Fiqhiyyah.  (Source same fatwa from islamqa as quoted above)

This fatwa from islamweb #[129516](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=129516) quotes a statement from ibn Taymiyyah saying abit otherwise than that quoted by ibn Quddamah: It is adding to majority abu Hanifa, a-Shafi'i and Ahmad and counting among those who permit prayer with tayammum imam Malik. I've heard something like this too, but I guess that this is only to ensure praying on time and that the prayer must be redone once one had taken ghusl.

On the whole scholars have these two options to re-establish the state of taharah: performing ghusl no matter if one may miss the time for the prayer or performing tayammum to be able to pray on time, but this doesn't re-establish taharah correctly and has very weak backup as quoted in the quotes from al-Mughni. It shouldn't be more important to pray on time than praying a valid prayer.

Answer (score 1):

As‘salaamu alaikum. There are two types of ghusl that we are allowed to do to cure major ritual impurity - ghusl as prescribed in the Qur‘an, and ghusl as prescribed in the Sunnah of Rasulullah (a.s.).

Ghusl as prescribed in the Qur‘an is very straightforward and can be done rather  quickly. Make intention for ghusl  and then wash your body with clean water. You do not even need to use soap to lather up. Just wash your body. Period.

A Qur‘anic saheeh ghusl can be done in 5 minutes. Fajr can also be done in 5 minutes.

A sincere muslim should make every effort to comply with the requirements of the Deen. Therefore, you should not go to the salat in a state of  janabat. Get up, make haste to do a Qur‘anic saheeh ghusl, get dressed, and make your salat.

Ideally, give yourself ample time to get ready  for prayer. Rouse yourself out of the bed and take care of business.

Ma‘as‘salaam, brother.

Comment: What if you only had 5 minutes instead of 15 minutes?

Comment: As‘salaamu alaikum. If you are in a state of janabat you must cure that before you make salat, because tahara (ritual purification) is one of the 8 fard-ash-shuroot (obligatory conditions) that must be satisfied before you can make salat. In the scenario you described you are going to miss the fajr salat. Make ghusl and then make the prayer up as soon as you can. Also, in the scenario you described you are at fault for missing the salat. If I were actually in that situation I would go give some sadaqa and fast for a few days as an attempt to expiate for the sin.

Comment: You mean I'm at fault for waking up accidentally 5 minutes before the time limit?

Comment: As‘salaamu alaikum, brother. You said you woke up in janabat. Perhaps a man might stay up so late having sexual intercourse that he oversleeps. Perhaps. Smh.... If a man had to go to work in the morning wouldn‘t it be irresponsible of him to stay up so late the night before that he oversleeps and either misses work or shows up late? As muslim men, we know we have an appointment with Allah every morning. We need to be responsible and make sure we make it to that appointment on time. But Allah knows best the circumstances of a man‘s  life. May He have mercy upon us all.

Comment: Intercourse? Is that what u thought about? Aren't there other causes like.. wet dreams. Anyways. Sure u can put the blame on me if u want. Not that it really matters what causes the person to wake up that late. You're  not supposed to be concerned about the cause in the context of this question. Because  I'm not asking you what am I supposed to do to prevent it. Rather the question is if you were in those 4 conditions, which step would you take next?

Comment: Wa'alaikum salam. Btw brother you said "You said you woke up in janabat."  When did I say it was me?  Nah don't worry, I won't blame you for that... Smh

Comment: As‘salaamu alaikum. My mistake for using the pronoun “you” in my comment. I can see how that personalizes the discussion, as contrasted with keeping it in the realm of the hypothetical. It was all hypothetical. And, yes, I veered off topic by delving into the hypothetical guy‘s reason for oversleeping. Forgive me, brother. Ma‘as‘salaam.